# Getting Serial and Hardware info from computers in AD OU with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get something working that will give me a .csv of computers in an OU along with the following:

- Computer Name
- Serial Number
- Model
- username (current or last known if applicable)
- hardware (ram, storage, cpu)

What I currently have seems to work except for the fact that I only get my PC's info several times in the .csv thoughts?

```
$inventory = @()
$inventory += foreach($computer in (get-adcomputer -filter *  -SearchBase "OU=myou,DC=mydc" | select -ExpandProperty name))
{
    #Make sure the computer is online
    if(test-connection -ComputerName $computer -quiet -count 1)
    {
        
        Write-Progress -Activity "Recording Hardware." -Status "Checking $PC"
        
        #Get info
        $computerInfo = gwmi win32_computersystem -Property username,name,model
        $OSInfo = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -property caption,version
        $CPUInfo = gwmi win32_processor -Property Name, Architecture
        $DriveInfo = gwmi win32_volume -filter 'drivetype = 3' | ? { $_.driveletter -match 'C:' } | select capacity, freespace
        $RAMInfo = Get-WmiObject CIM_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | % {[math]::round(($_.sum / 1GB),2)}
        $Serial = Get-WmiObject win32_bios | select serialnumber

    

        #Create an object for each computer
        $CompObj = New-Object System.Object
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Computer -value $ComputerInfo.Name
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Username -value $ComputerInfo.username
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Model -value $ComputerInfo.model
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "OS Name" -value $OSInfo.caption
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Version -value $OSInfo.version
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CPUName -value $CPUInfo.name
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Architecture -value $arch
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Capacity -value $($DriveInfo.capacity/1GB)
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name FreeSpace -value $($DriveInfo.freespace/1GB)
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name RAM -value $RAMInfo
                $CompObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Serial -value $Serial
                $CompObj
    }
}
$inventory | Export-Csv c:\temp\inventory2.csv
```

Comment: You need to add `-ComputerName $Computer` to each of your `gwmi` calls

Comment: @TheMadTechnician where would I add that in the line for each?

Comment: You can put it almost anywhere after the cmdlet and before a pipe. If you need a specific place, put it after the class like `gwmi win32_something -ComputerName $Computer -property stuff, things | ?{$_.stuff -eq 'neat'}`